# Problems running Trinity - possible the read file format?

Tags: bioinformatics, pbs

I'm trying to run Trinity (2.6.6.) to analyze a metatranscriptome, but it is giving me the following errors (copied from the *.o file):

> **Error, pairs.K25.stats is empty**. Be sure to check your fastq reads and ensure that the read names are identical except for the /1 or /2
>   designation. at
>   /fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/util/insilico_read_normalization.pl
>   line 921. CMD finished (1209 seconds) **Error, cmd**:
>   /fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/util/insilico_read_normalization.pl
>   --seqType fq --JM 112G --max_cov 50 --min_cov 1 --CPU 28 --output /fs/project/PAS1117/GuiDH/Trinity_tests/trinity_out_dir/insilico_read_normalization
>   --max_pct_stdev 10000 --left /fs/project/PAS1117/Tara_Euk/upwelling-v2/ERR1719296_1.fastq.gz
>   --right /fs/project/PAS1117/Tara_Euk/upwelling-v2/ERR1719296_2.fastq.gz
>   --pairs_together --PARALLEL_STATS died with ret 512 at /fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/Trinity line 2581.
>   main::process_cmd('/fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/util/insilico_read_...')
>   called at /fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/Trinity line 3127
>   main::normalize('/fs/project/PAS1117/GuiDH/Trinity_tests/trinity_out_dir/insil...',
>   50, 'ARRAY(0x2735d58)', 'ARRAY(0x277bb80)') called at
>   /fs/project/PAS1117/modules/trinity/2.6.6/Trinity line 3074

Could someone check if there is something wrong with the batch file sent? (pasted here below)

```
PBS -N trinity_test3
PBS -l walltime=40:00:00
PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=48
PBS -j oe
PBS -m abe
PBS -A PAA0034
set -x cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR 
module use /fs/project/PAS1117/modulefiles 
module load samtools/1.3.1 
module load bowtie2/2.2.9 
module load jellyfish/2.2.9 
module load salmon/0.9.1 
module load trinity/2.6.6 
**Trinity --seqType fq --left /fs/project/PAS1117/Tara_Euk/upwelling-v2/ERR1719296_1.fastq.gz --right /fs/project/PAS1117/Tara_Euk/upwelling-v2/ERR1719296_2.fastq.gz --CPU 28 --max_memory 112G** 
echo $PBS_JOBID echo $PBS-JOBNAME
```

Comment: How is this related to assembly?

Comment: The error says the reads couldn't be paired. Did you verify that the read names in the FASTQ files are identical?